# How does Google know that I've got an old version of Chromium?

Tags: networking

I use the Chromium web browser, and when I visit google's home page
(www.google.co.uk), I get the message "We've detected you're using an older
version of Chrome. Update to stay secure". The message appears at the top,
under the web-address box.

How does this website KNOW that I've got an old version of Chromium?

Can websites IN GENERAL, determine the following:

1. Determine things about your browser?
2. Determine things about other software you have on your hard drive?
3. Determine what files you have on your hard drive?

Regarding 1. and 2. above, if the answer is "yes", then WHAT things can websites determine about your browser and other software?

If the answer to 1., 2., or 3. is "yes", then HOW do websites do it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't [relate specifically to Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  It might be better placed on superuser.com, but it would likely be a duplicate over there.

Answer (score 2):

Usually browser reports 'USER AGENT STRING' to server, which looks like this:

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36

You can freely change your user agent string, only problem might be that particular sites optimized for particular browsers will show some bugs here and there.

That was especially true in the past then MS browsers has 90% if internet share and were terrible in support of standards, so there was a lot of sites which didn't support anything but Explorer.

That is in ideal world, in real world you just downloaded binary browser from somewhere. What kind of guarantee you have? Program itself, working under your account has rights to transfer all your files to remote side. So in the end, it is matter of your trust to provider. Don't be scared, because Google and Mozilla are respectable companies, they probably would not do nothing like that. But that's the reason why some people strictly use only software built from sources by third party.